# how to replace flat file created by a export data wizard on a schedule task with server agent

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-agent

i already create a SSIS package on SSMS and scheduled in Server Agent, it create succesfully my '.csv' file but i want to overwrite the file every night when the scheduled job start again.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

In your SSIS package, in the Flat File Destination, make sure the box **Overwrite data in the file** is checked. When the package runs each night, the file will be overwritten with new data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [File System Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task?view=sql-server-2017) in your Control Flow.

> The File System task performs operations on files and directories in
>   the file system. For example, by using the File System task, a package
>   can create, move, or **delete** directories and files. You can also use
>   the File System task to set attributes on files and directories. For
>   example, the File System task can make files hidden or read-only.